# Diagram a New Database for an ASP.NET Application?

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, diagram

I'm about to create a new application - somewhat like a CRM. I'm thinking it would be best to diagram out all the tables/fields before I begin...but not sure what is the best way to do so? Are there tools in VS? MSSMS? Something else? I want to quickly and thoroughly create the database the application will use for its back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171971%28VS.80%29.aspx article explains pretty well how to create database diagrams using Microsoft SQL Management Studio. You can download SQLMS here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Database/

The nice thing about this approach is that your diagram is also your database so you don't have to create the diagram and then create the database, you can get them both done at the same time.

Comment: Definitely a good way to go once the data structure has been implemented - though I think the OP's question was more regarding the initial design.

Answer (score 1):

I quite like to use Microsoft Visio to map this sort of stuff out.

Or even better - a wipeboard!

Comment: Visio can be a nice way to do it for sure. Note that only the enterprise version of Visio will allow you to export your diagram to create an actual database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this inside Visual Studio. Just set up a Database and in the Server Explorer, create a new diagram. The way to do this differs in different VS Versions.

[VS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171971%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Another approach would be to use the Management Studio Express

You can get this one [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08E52AC2-1D62-45F6-9A4A-4B76A8564A2B&displaylang=de).

Comment: As per comment below - I think the OP's question was more regarding the initial design.